# Where to write custom Jquery code in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I am new to trying out Dreamwweaver, and I am trying to write a simple custome Jquery code, but I don't know where to write it persey. Is it like with CSS where I have to create a separate stylesheet so-to-speak? of do I write it like an inline element for each page I create, and if so, do I write it near the top or the bottom? or do I group all of my script somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DW or any other editor you use the .js (javascript) extension to write Jquery code. Also you can just add it to the html document with the  here goes code  tag.

Comment: okay, I figured that out by Starting a new custom.js file and I saved in the same folder as my index.html, how do I link the two so that my index.html will run my custom.js file?

Comment: This should work: `code  <script src="folder/custom.js"><script>` Depends how you want to execute the script you can add into the body or head tag.